# JLabel doesnt appear when executing the program

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

I do not know what's going on, I already tried many things to fix this. I know it sounds to be a silly mistake, but it already took me some time. Below is the code. if anyone knows what to do please tell me.

```
public class Window extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

    public static final int WIDTH = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getWidth();
    public static final int HEIGHT = (int) toolkit.getScreenSize().getHeight();

    public Dimension windowDimension = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

    JButton buttonStartGame = new JButton();
    JButton buttonTechTreeOverview = new JButton();
    JButton buttonOptions = new JButton();
    JButton buttonExit = new JButton();

    ImageIcon buttonStartGameIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("buttonStartGameIcon.png"));
    ImageIcon buttonTechTreeOverviewIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("buttonTechTreeOverviewIcon.png"));
    ImageIcon buttonOptionsIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("buttonOptionsIcon.png"));
    ImageIcon buttonExitIcon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("buttonExitIcon.png"));

    JLabel backLabel = new JLabel();

    public Window(String name) {

        setLayout(null);
        setSize(windowDimension);
        setUndecorated(true);
        setTitle(name);
        setVisible(true);
        setResizable(true);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        modifyCompontes();

        startMenu();

        System.out.println("Thread is ok");

    }

    public void startMenu() {

        backLabel.add(buttonExit);
        backLabel.add(buttonStartGame);
        backLabel.add(buttonTechTreeOverview);
        backLabel.add(buttonOptions);

        add(backLabel);
    }

    public void StartGame() {

    }

    public void TechTreeOverviewStart() {

    }

    public void gameOptions() {

    }

    private void modifyCompontes() {

        try {
            backLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(
                    imageResizer(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("fundo.png")), WIDTH, HEIGHT)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        backLabel.setBounds(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);

        buttonStartGame.setIcon(buttonStartGameIcon);
        buttonStartGame.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 100);
        buttonStartGame.addActionListener(this);

        buttonTechTreeOverview.setIcon(buttonTechTreeOverviewIcon);
        buttonTechTreeOverview.setBounds(100, 250, 200, 100);
        buttonTechTreeOverview.addActionListener(this);

        buttonOptions.setIcon(buttonOptionsIcon);
        buttonOptions.setBounds(100, 400, 200, 100);
        buttonOptions.addActionListener(this);

        buttonExit.setIcon(buttonExitIcon);
        buttonExit.setBounds(100, 550, 200, 100);
        buttonExit.addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == buttonStartGame) {
            StartGame();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == buttonTechTreeOverview) {
            TechTreeOverviewStart();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == buttonOptions) {
            gameOptions();
        }

        if (e.getSource() == buttonExit) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public Image imageResizer(Image image, int width, int height) {
        BufferedImage resizedImage = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        Graphics2D g = resizedImage.createGraphics();
        g.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION, RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BILINEAR);
        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null);
        g.dispose();
        return resizedImage;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Don't use a null layout. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers.
2. Add all the component to the frame BEFORE making the frame visible.